# SQL Server inconsistently reporting missing indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, database-tuning-advisor, performance-tuning

I have a stored procedure that is not performing well and I am trying to tune it.  I am confused by what I see in SSMS and the Database Tuning Engine Advisor.

In SSMS I have 'Include Actual Execution Plan' turned on.  If I execute the stored procedure and look at the execution plan tab, no missing index is reported.  However if I take the body of the stored procedure and paste it into SSMS and execute the raw SQL, the execution plan tab does show a missing index.  Outside of that the plans displayed are the same.

Additionally, if I select either the stored procedure or the SQL statement and ask SSMS to Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor (from the query menu) no missing index is reported for either scenario.

Why does executing the direct SQL statement show a missing index in SSMS but not in the Tuning Advisor?  Why would the missing index report be different for the direct sql statement vs the stored procedure that does the exact same thing?

Comment: What are the issues you are seeing when you write "not performing well"?

Comment: 50% cpu on the database server when the stored procedure is executed with 50 concurrent users.  100% cpu when going up to 100 concurrent users.  Under testing conditions the sproc returns 100 rows from a dataset of 1000 possible.  DB server is an Intel Xeon CPU E5- 2686 v4 @ 2.30 GHz with 61GB of ram.

Comment: By saying the plans "are the same" - to what level of detail did you confirm this? Can you post the good plan XML and the bad plan XML somewhere so we can compare too? Note that executing just the code from inside the stored procedure can be different than executing the procedure directly for a variety of reasons, particularly if you change input parameters to local variables ([video](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/local-variable-vs-stored-procedure/) | [blog post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/)).

Comment: In any case, if the plans are "the same" (except for the MissingIndexGroup nodes in the XML, of course), I highly doubt any performance difference is due to the absence or presence of a missing index warning. I think there are more fundamental differences you're not seeing.

Comment: Do note that the system doesn't always display the missing index warning in the graphical execution plan. The only certain way to identify if missing indexes have been spotted is to look at the XML view, and search for MissingIndex in the text.  **IMPORTANT:** There can be more than one missing index block in a complex query. Look for all of these blocks. This can cause confusion when there is no MissingIndex block early in the XML, where it "normally" is.